# Vue js calling action inside action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have the following actions in my Vuex store:

```
import { HTTP } from '@/services/http'
import router from '@/router'

export const actions = {
  loginUser ({ commit, state }, params) {
    HTTP.post('v1/login.json', { email: params.email, password: params.password })
    .then(response => {
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.token)
      router.push({name: 'Hello'})
    }).catch(error => {
      commit('SET_LOGIN_ERROR', error.response.data.error)
    })
  },

  myAccount ({ commit }) {
    HTTP.get('v1/my_account.json').headers({'Authorization': ('Token token=' + localStorage.getItem('access_token'))})
    .then(response => {
      commit('SET_USER', response.data)
    })
  }
}
```

I want to launch `myAccount` action when `loginUser` succeeds. How can I do that?

I've tried something like this:

```
import { HTTP } from '@/services/http'
import router from '@/router'

export const actions = {
  loginUser ({ commit, state }, params) {
    HTTP.post('v1/login.json', { email: params.email, password: params.password })
    .then(response => {
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.token)
      router.push({name: 'Hello'})
    }).catch(error => {
      commit('SET_LOGIN_ERROR', error.response.data.error)
    })
  },

  myAccount ({ dispatch, commit, state }, payload) {
    dispatch('loginUser', payload)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log('dupa')
        // Do this when loginUser finished
      })
  }
}
```

but this not works...

Answer (score 4):

actions receive the `context` object, so you can simply either pass the entire object or add dispatch to your destructuring assignment :

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  actions: {
    foo(context) {
        console.log('foo called');
      },
      bar({dispatch}) {
        setTimeout(() => dispatch('foo'), 1000)
      }
  }
});
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y1527vxh/

Answer (score 1):

Since vue actions can be asynchronous you can add dispatch handler to an action to call another action when it is done;

```
export const actions = {
  loginUser ({ commit, state }, params) {
    ... // some http request or what would you like to do
  },

  myAccount ({ dispatch, commit, state }, payload) {
    dispatch('loginUser', payload)
      .then((res) => {
        ...
        // Do this when loginUser finished
      })
  },
}
```

I am doing autentication in my projects like this, i am using axios btw:

```
loginUser ({ dispatch, commit, state }, payload) {
  let loginData = {
    username: payload.username,
    password: payload.password
  }
  return axios.post(state.url, loginData)
           .then((res) => {
             // You can console.log(res.data) to see if your token data is fine
             window.localStorage.setItem('AuthTokens', JSON.stringify(res.data))
             dispatch('myAccount', { tokens: res.data })
           })
           .catch((err) => {
             // Error handling...
           })
},

myAccount ({ commit, state }, { tokens }) {
  let headerOptions = {
    // Header options with tokens.access_token...
  }
  return axios.get(state.url, headerOptions)
           .then((res) => {
             // You have the user data
             console.log(res.data)
           })
           .catch((err) => {
             // Error handling...
           })
}
```

Comment: I've tried Your solution but it does not work. I added console.log statement into `.then` block but I cannot see that log in browser.

Comment: I think there must be a problem with loginUser action then maybe it's because you are not returning your request, i updated my answer the way i am doing in my project.